# Running ASP.NET MVC 6 Web API from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I create a MVC 6 Web API project that is running as expected from Visual Studio, when I'm however deploying to production I'm getting a

> An error occured while starting the application

error.

[image]

I did the following on the production machine

- Installed ASP.NET 5 from https://get.asp.net
- Made sure that the production environment is running the same dnx version 
  that the application was published with
- Installed HttpPlatformHandler 1.2
- Set the application pool .NET CLR Version to No Managed Code
- Pointed the root location to the wwwroot folder

Is there anything else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run into 500 errors, remember that ASP.NET 5 application can be self hosted,

- Open a command prompt
- Browse to the application directory
- Type in web.cmd

I had some reference problems within my application that was listed in my command prompt which I subsequently fixed and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

500 can be thrown by different failures. Take a look on http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html what u've missed in your configuration.
And you should call it ASP.NET Core 1